# How to list all registered users using asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I`m using the asp.net user identity method for creating users and login, and i was searching for solution for this but i couldn't find out how to do it...

So my question is: is there someway to list all users in my index action of Account controller?

Answer (score 2):

```
userManager.Users.ToList();
```

Where userManager is of type UserManager

Answer (score 1):

`UserManager` do this for you. Use `Users` property. Its type is `IQueryable<TUser>` so you can query on it.

As @Amit says one example is:

```
userManager.Users.ToList();
```

You can call it through your MVC Controllers like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return userManager.Users.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain little more or reference some links where i can search the solution myself, im relatively new to asp.net...

Comment: You should go through all the items under Getting Started. http://www.asp.net/identity